# PHP fatal error opening required file

Tags: php, zend-framework, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm having problems debugging this php error. '/app/bootstrap.php' exists so not sure why I'm getting this error? Can anyone help? Thanks

```
[24-Mar-2017 10:42:50 Europe/London] PHP Warning: require_once(/app/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.com/index.php on line 2
[24-Mar-2017 10:42:50 Europe/London] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/app/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.30/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.com/index.php on line 2
```

Comment: it could be a htaccess problem, or your path is not correct. does your htaccess work?

Comment: There is no .htaccess file

Comment: also not in: "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/" because the htaccess is most of the time placed in the root directory of your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path `/app/bootstrap.php` looks like a root path ( and the root isn't your website root, but your Mac root directory).

Change  require path to `__DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php'`, it means to require a sccript that in /app/bootstrap.php relative to CURRENT directory.

Comment: Thanks for this. From which PHP version was this changed, do you know?

Comment: What do you mean from which php version? Its always was like this. MY best bet, that there is a CONSTANT that supose to be point to some (may be root directory) and that is located before '/app/bootstrap.php' was just udndefined, which trigger this error.

Comment: Just seems like something has changed for this to break, basically I'm trying to revive an old PHP application built on Zend framework which apparently it used to work and then it suddenly started getting 500 errors. I can now load the homepage on my local setup but subsequent pages just show 'Index of /subpage' instead of actual content. now trying to get to the bottom of why the sub page aren't loading

Comment: I would suggest you in general turn error log E_ALL and see all madness that heppening under the hook, obviously you see only fatal errors now.

Comment: all PHP errors are being logged, the only error I'm getting is Apache `[Mon Mar 27 09:57:31 2017] [error] [client ::1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/user/Documents/DEV/example/apache/.DS_Store, referer: http://local.example.com/`